# Recycler view can't select all items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` with select all option.this option select screen visible items only. Not all select. But I scroll top to bottom after selected. what is the problem?

Adapter class:

```
public class FilterBrandAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilterBrandAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<FilterBrandDataModel> mBrandModelArraylist;
    private Context mContext;
    private TinyDB mPrefDb;
    private boolean isSelectedAll;
    public static final String PREF_SELECTED_ALL = "selectedAll";
    private CartTotalListener mCartListener;

    public void selectAll() {
        Log.e("onClickSelectAll", "yes");
        isSelectedAll = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deselectAll() {
        Log.e("onClickSelectAll", "no");
        isSelectedAll = false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CheckBox cbItemTitle;


        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cbItemTitle = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_filter_brand_title);
            itemView.setClickable(true);

        }
    }

    public FilterBrandAdapter(BrandFilterActivity activity, ArrayList<FilterBrandDataModel> mArrayList) {

        this.mContext = activity;
        this.mBrandModelArraylist = mArrayList;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        try {
            this.mCartListener = ((CartTotalListener) mContext);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement AdapterCallback.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public FilterBrandAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_brand_items, parent, false);

        mPrefDb = new TinyDB(mContext);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final FilterBrandDataModel brandsData = mBrandModelArraylist.get(position);

        holder.cbItemTitle.setText(mBrandModelArraylist.get(position).getCategoryName());

        //set adapter classcheckbox change listener for if clicked or not
        holder.cbItemTitle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (holder.cbItemTitle.isChecked()) {

                    //if check box checked selected checkbox saved in tinyDB
                    int getPosition = (int) buttonView.getTag();
                    mBrandModelArraylist.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    mPrefDb.putBoolean(brandsData.getCategoryName(), true);
                    holder.cbItemTitle.setChecked(true);
                    Log.e("checked item-->", brandsData.getCategoryName());
                    mCartListener.onMethodCallback();


                } else {

                    //else check box un-checked selected checkbox save checkbox is un-checked in tinyDB
                    int getPosition = (int) buttonView.getTag();
                    mBrandModelArraylist.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    mPrefDb.putBoolean(brandsData.getCategoryName(), false);
                    holder.cbItemTitle.setChecked(false);

                    Log.e("un-checked item-->", brandsData.getCategoryName());
                    mCartListener.onMethodCallback();

                }


            }
        });

        //select & deselect  all checkbox in recyclerview
        if (!isSelectedAll) {
            holder.cbItemTitle.setTag(position);
            holder.cbItemTitle.setChecked(mBrandModelArraylist.get(position).isSelected());
            holder.cbItemTitle.setChecked(false);

        } else {
            holder.cbItemTitle.setTag(position);
            holder.cbItemTitle.setChecked(mBrandModelArraylist.get(position).isSelected());
            holder.cbItemTitle.setChecked(true);

        }

        //save selected (or) deselect checkbox with position in tinyDB
        holder.cbItemTitle.setTag(position);
        holder.cbItemTitle.setChecked(mBrandModelArraylist.get(position).isSelected());

        boolean checked = mPrefDb.getBoolean(brandsData.getCategoryName(), true);
        holder.cbItemTitle.setChecked(checked);
    }

@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mBrandModelArraylist.size();
    }
}
```

I use interface(mCartListener.onMethodCallback()) for notify selected items & display items counts in text view.

my interface:

```
@Override
public void onMethodCallback() {

    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

    //checking which items are selected in adapter class & save into array list
    for (FilterBrandDataModel brandDataModel : mArrayList) {
        if (brandDataModel.isSelected()) {
            array.add(brandDataModel.getCategoryName());
        }
    }

    int size = array.size();

    if (size == mArrayList.size()) {
        mPrefDb.putString(PREF_SELECTED_BRANDS_TOT, "true");
        String text = String.valueOf(size) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.msg_selected);
        mBrandResults.setText(text);
    } else {
        mPrefDb.putString(PREF_SELECTED_BRANDS_TOT, "false");
        String text = String.valueOf(size) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.msg_selected);
        mBrandResults.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get your problem. You want to select all visible items or the whole list?

Comment: i want to select whole list of items.but now my code select only visible items?what can i do?

Comment: add boolean in your model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RecyclerView` loads the data while scrolling, but I need all data in it without scrolling. So, I changed the `RecyclerView` in `ScrollView` like that:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        />
    </ScrollView>
```

then, in the `Activity`,

```
RecyclerView.setNestedScrollEnabled(false);
```

I use the `ScrollView` to scroll items. That's it.

Comment: Would not recommend that. You don't need all data. You only have to modify the complete list not only the visible items. Check my solution. You won't need the flag `isSelectedAll` anymore.

Comment: i need all items for select all

Comment: You have all items inside `mBrandModelArraylist`. They're only not visible because the recyclerview do his job. If you scroll down the recyclerview will update the visible items with the right content.

Comment: ya.correct.but i need to show contents without scrolling.because show all contents.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Your screen has a limited size. You can't show all items at the same time. If you have for example 100 items you have to scroll. And if you implement my solution, you update the data in the background and the reclyclerview will recycle the viewholder and show the right content.

Comment: no.i don't mean that.in orientation changes all checkbox could select on clicking select all option.but using above method it working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that you only switch a flag in `selectAll()` (*isSelectedAll = true;*). In your adapter there will be for example 3 visible items (i don't know how big they are at your screen). One item is represented by one viewholder. After you switch the flag and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` the function `onBindViewHolder()` will be called for every visible item -> in my example 3 times. In this function you decide with `if (!isSelectedAll) {` if the checkbox should be selected. So it will never be called for all items.

**Solution:**

Change

```
public void selectAll() {
    Log.e("onClickSelectAll", "yes");
    isSelectedAll = true;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

To

```
public void selectAll() {
    Log.e("onClickSelectAll", "yes");
    for(FilterBrandDataModel brandsData : mBrandModelArraylist) {
         mPrefDb.putBoolean(brandsData.getCategoryName(), true);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And the same for `deselectAll()`.